# Running into a print problem with floats and integers

Tags: python

I am trying to create a program where the user is asked to input their credit score and based upon if it is less than or = to 650, they will have to put either 10% or 20% downpayment on the house. The problem I'm having is when running my code instead of printing the downpayment amount it just prints the decimal "0.1" or "0.2" multiple times as shown below. I've included my simple program below.

```
credit_score = float(input("What is your credit score? "))
house_price = 1000000

if credit_score <= 650:
    print('down_payement = ' + str(0.2) * house_price)

else:
    print('down_payement = ' + str(0.1) * house_price)
```

Comment: `str(0.2) * house_price` should be `str(0.2 * house_price)`. Voting to close as typo. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [ask]. For debugging help in the future, make a [mre], which will help you catch basic mistakes like this.

Comment: Although, you can do it cleaner by letting `print` convert to `str` for you: `print('down_payement =', 0.2 * house_price)`

Comment: @wjandrea or just `print(f'down payment = {0.2 * house_price:.2f}')` for some decimal places formatting as well...

Comment: To be clear, you were getting the string multiple times because that's string multiplication. For example, `'ab' * 3` -> `'ababab'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert to string after multiplication:

```
credit_score = float(input("What is your credit score? "))
house_price = 1000000

if credit_score <= 650:
    print('down_payement = ' + str(0.2 * house_price))

else:
    print('down_payement = ' + str(0.1 * house_price))
```